# Application_Start in a web garden environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

Running under IIS 7.5, I have a web garden. When IIS is restarted, does it only call `Application_Start` one time or is it one time for each web garden instance? I would like definitive proof.

Also, as I understand it, each web garden instance is an exact clone. That means that if I add something to HttpContext.Cache in one instance it may not be available to HttpContext.Cache in another instance, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each web garden instance is, to my knowledge, it's own process completely. That means the cache is not shared, Application_Start is not shared, etc. Pretend like it's running on a completely different server, and you should get a good understanding of exactly what will/won't happen.

Comment: From reading [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) it appears that `Application_Start` is only run for the first instance.

Comment: @scottm, where do you see in there that it's only run for the first instance? I see "The first time an ASP.NET page or process is requested in an application, a new instance of HttpApplication is created" which is exactly what I'd expect - a new HttpApplication for each process.

Comment: the next sentence. Is "an application" defined as a single CPU application instance in a web garden, or as all instances in the web garden?

Comment: Why don't you just give it a try? Add a log statement to the applicatoin_start, and see how many times it happens.